# Install XPDF in Mac/OS

Tags: macports

How we can install XPDF via Mac Ports? Or if another methods for the installation of XPDF in the Mac/OS platform exists?

Comment: From a comment you have installed xpdf so the question is not correct

Comment: @mark: the question is clear enough and the answers are spot on. The fact that the question doesn't correspond to the problem the OP is facing is of no concern here :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can install it using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) too.

First you need to tap `homebrew/x11`:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/x11
```

Then you can easily install it with:

```
$ brew install xpdf
```

Answer (score 2):

That might look too easy an answer :):

```
/usr/bin/sudo port install xpdf
```

Comment: I did but I get xpdf command not found

Comment: OK, you should have asked for this key point within your OQ. Please add it, and by the way, please add the output of `echo ${PATH}`.

Answer (score -2):

`xpdf` is available through the [Homebrew project](https://brew.sh). Once `brew` is installed, you can install `xpdf` using the command:

```
brew install homebrew/x11/xpdf
```

Comment: How does this improve on or differ from http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/171012/237